# Mocking a service that throws an exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to test a JSF Backing-Bean method "isInProgress" that delegates to a service method "isInProgress". When the service method throws an exception, the bean should put an event on a specific event logger and return false.

When I debug the following test, I get into the catch-block. The mocked service does not throw the exception, but returns a "default answer" which is false for th boolean. **What am I doing wrong?**

I also wonder if the try-catch around the "when" call can be avoided somehow, as the actual exception is swallowed by the bean under test. In fact I think "declaratively" passing the name of the method to the "when" should suffice. **Is there a way to get that cleaner ?**

```
@Test
public void testIsInProgressExeption() {
    //prepare object and inputs
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    MyService service = mock(MyAdapterService.class);
    bean.setService(service);

    try {
        when(bean.getService().isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());
    } catch (Exception e) {

        //prepare expected object and result
        MyBean expectedBean = new MyBean();
        expectedBean.setService(service);
        boolean expected = false;

        //execute method under test
        boolean actual = bean.isInProgress();

        //check return values and exceptions
        assertEquals(expected, actual);

        //check that bean did not change unexpectedly
        assertTrue(bean.equals(expectedBean));

        //check sideeffects on event log
        assertTrue(logEvents.containsMessage("MDI09"));
    }

}
```

For reference here is the updated Test:

```
@Test
public void testIsInProgressExeption() throws Exception {
    //prepare object and inputs
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    MyService service = mock(MyAdapterService.class);
    bean.setService(service);

    when(bean.getService().isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());

    //prepare expected object and result
    MyBean expectedBean = new MyBean();
    expectedBean.setService(service);
    boolean expected = false;

    //execute method under test
    boolean actual = bean.isInProgress();

    //check return values and exceptions
    assertEquals(expected, actual);

    //check that bean did not change unexpectedly
    assertTrue(bean.equals(expectedBean));

    //check sideeffects on event log
    assertTrue(logEvents.containsMessage("MDI09"));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the when clause out of the try block and change it to:

```
when(service.isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

Now it should throw an exception when called.

Comment: but service.isInProgress() throws an Exception, so the compiler forces me to deal with it !

Comment: Ah adding a throws to the test-decl does it.

Comment: Add the Exception to your test methods signature

Answer (score 0):

For the records, I was doing state-base testing. Interestingly, Fowler posted in http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html a very nice article that goes quite the same route but then differentiates it from mocking and interaction-based testing.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. First you should lay out your test with the **BDD** or **AAA** keywords, with BDD :

```
@Test public void testIsInProgressExeption() {
    // given

    // when

    // then

}
```

In the ***given*** part you will write your fixture, i.e. the setup of your test scenario. In the ***when*** part you will call the production code i.e. the tested subject. Lastly in the ***when*** part you will write your verifications and or assertions.

Stubs go in the fixture, so this line is misplaced, it doesn't belong here, it' just a definition of the behavior.

```
when(bean.getService().isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

However you should directly the service reference instead of the `bean.getService()`, this is akward.

I don't really understand why you are creating a new instance of the bean in the catch clause, this is weird. But here's how I wold write the test. Note by the way I explain in the unit test name what behavior the test is actully testing, writing this in camel case is way to painful to read, so I use the **underscored** convention, **it's ok in tests**.

```
@Test public void when_service_throw_Exception_InProgress_then_returns_false() throws Exception {
    // given
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    MyService service = mock(MyAdapterService.class);
    bean.setService(service);

    when(service.isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());

    // when
    boolean result = bean.isInProgress();

    // then
    assertFalse(result);
}
```

Also I would split the assertion on the event, this a different behavior :

```
@Test public void when_service_throw_Exception_InProgress_then_log_event_MDI09() throws Exception {
    // given
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    MyService service = mock(MyAdapterService.class);
    bean.setService(service);
    // somehow set up the logEvents collaborator

    when(service.isInProgress()).thenThrow(new Exception());

    // when
    bean.isInProgress();

    // then
    assertTrue(logEvents.containsMessage("MDI09"));
}
```

You can even go further to simplify the fixture, if you use JUnit, you write this code :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyBeanTest {
    @Mock MyService service;
    @Mock LogEvents logEvents;
    @InjectMocks MyBean bean;


    @Test public void when_service_throw_Exception_InProgress_then_log_event_MDI09() throws Exception {
        // given
        when(service.isInProgress()).thenThrow(Exception.class);

        // when
        bean.isInProgress();

        // then
        verify(logEvents).logEvent("MDI09");
    }
}
```

In the example above I also extrapolated on the log event stuff, but it is just to give the idea of what's possible.

Comment: I dont know much about testing frameworks, but as you see in the comments my approach is very systematic, and in fact I don't know of any better approach (and it uses simple means!). I test not only input samples against return values. I also test state-changes on the object under test (which should not happen in this case), and possible side-effects in other objects. Besides, your tone is quite agressive.

Comment: I'm sorry if the tone seemed harsh or agressive this wasn't my intent. Anyway the main idea was to give a progressive way to have specific and focalised tests, doing that you can potentially drive your code to a better design. The simple fact of commenting what the is doing in the test is a **smell**. Also the real intents of your test isn't expressed in `testIsInProgressException`, i.e. testing there's no state side effect in your bean it's worth writing a test for that.

Comment: Practicing TDD can help in this matter. Here's a great book were there many valuable information [Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com). This blog from James Carr list commons [test anti-patterns](http://blog.james-carr.org/2006/11/03/tdd-anti-patterns/). Of course there is many other interesting reading.